# Rails: Modeling Straightforward Data Using has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling, has-many-through

I have a pretty simple set of data requirements to do with pets and veterinarians.

- An `owner` can have many `pets`
- A `pet` can have one `owner`
- A `pet` can be treated by (belongs_to) many `veterinarians`
- A `veterinarian` can treat (have_many) `pets`

`Owner` and `Veterinarian` are both subclasses of `User` using STI.

Here's some code:

```
class Owner < User
  has_many :pets
  has_many :veterinarians, :through => :pets
end

class Veterinarian < User
  attr_accessible :clinic_name

  has_many :pets
  has_many :owners, :through => :pets
end


class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :date_of_birth, :species, :breed, :gender, :neutered

  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :veterinarian
end
```

And here is the spec that is failing:

```
it "has various veterinarians" do
  o = Owner.make!(:email => 'owner1@gmail.com')
  v1 = Veterinarian.make!(:email => 'vet_1@gmail.com')
  v2 = Veterinarian.make!(:email => 'vet_2@gmail.com')
  p = Pet.make!(:name => 'fluffy')

  o.pets << p
  v1.pets << p
  v2.pets << p

  o.pets.should have(2).records
  o.veterinarians.should have(2).records
end
```

The `make!` stuff is to do with using machinist fixture replacement. It just factory creates the objects.

The failure occurs on the last line. It turns out that o.veterinarians only has 1 record. I understand that a `pet` is not a join table in the traditional sense, inasmuch as I don't want to create a whole new pet each time I create a relationship between an owner and a veterinarian. Should I be using a schema more like `Owner` has_many `Pet`s, `Pet` belongs_to :owner and `Pet` has_and_belongs_to_many `Veterinarian`s?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a join table between the `Pet` and the `Veterinarian`. Let's call it `Treatment`:

```
class Treatment < ...
...
  belongs_to :pet
  belongs_to :veterinarian
...
end

class Veterinarian < ...
...
  has_many :treatments
  has_many :pets, through: :treatments
...
end

class Pet < ...
...
  has_many :treatments
  has_many :veterinarians, through: :treatments
...
end
```